# How to add missing aesthetics: label to geom_label()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get the error below:

> ```
> Error: geom_label requires the following missing aesthetics: label
> ```

When I run the following script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data("murders")

murders %>%
  ggplot(aes(population, total, lavel=abb, color=region)) +
  geom_label()
```

How can I add the missing aesthetics or how to solve the problem?

Comment: you have a typo `label` and not `lavel`. Without the typo, I get the correct plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data("murders")

murders %>%
  ggplot(aes(population, total, lavel=abb, color=region)) +
  geom_label(aes(population, total, label=state))
```

Comment: Should be `ggplot(murders, aes(population, total, label=abb, color=region)) +
  geom_label()`